# How to access a variable from inside a function

Tags: python, if-statement

File structure:

```
def mainStuff():
  for a in aa:
    aName = aa[a].split('')[-1].split('-')[5]

   # Do other important stuff so I can't return early

def replaceOne():
  if aName.split('_')[1] == "android":
    aName = aName.replace('_android','Android')

  return aName

def replaceTwo():
  if aName.split('_')[4:7] == "abc":
    aName = aName.replace('abc','Tom')

  return aName
```

I want the two if statement blocks to run consecutively, so I have decided to put them in separate functions. However, as `aName` is generated when the loop runs, my functions are unable to get the variable. I cannot use `return` as the function has to run to its completion for my output to work.

I have tried using `yield` but the function just ends prematurely.

How do I get `aName` and pass it through my other functions?

Comment: @deceze I have added the file structure, how does it look now?

Comment: Revise if aName.split('_')[4:7] == "abc": , it seems dont do what you want to do

Comment: Oh I just added random symbols in there, please don't mind. I'm using other symbols that are not - or _ @Wonka

Comment: @Yuu your question is about fundamental python syntax, i.e. how to pass parameters to functions, and you should focus on understanding that properly. But once you have this working, you might want to looking into using [regex substitution](https://lzone.de/examples/Python%20re.sub) to solve this problem.

Comment: @Dan Thanks! I will work on my fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `aName` to your functions a parameter. See the parameters section in [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp). In your case, try adjusting your code as follows:

```
def mainStuff():
    for a in aa:
        aName = aa[a].split('')[-1].split('-')[5]
        aName = replaceOne(aName)
        aName = replaceTwo(aName)

def replaceOne(aName: str) -> str:
    if aName.split('_')[1] == "android":
        aName = aName.replace('_android','Android')
    return aName

def replaceTwo(aName: str) -> str:
    if aName.split('_')[4:7] == "abc":
        aName = aName.replace('abc','Tom')
    return aName
```

Comment: As this is the first time I see this syntax, could you explain what it does? `def foo(arg: type) -> type`? Is this even valid python?

Comment: @Dschoni these are type hints. Here are some resources: https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/#annotations and https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/ and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/

Comment: Wow. That's awesome for making cythoning easier. Thank you!